# Write PHP path +url extension inside PHP if / include

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Working with Wordpress and want to use the PHP function  inside this code

```
<?php if ( is_page(19074) ) { 
include("/home/something/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/folder/page1.html");
} 
elseif ( is_page(18956) ) { 
include("home/something/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/folder/page2.html");
}  
elseif ( is_page(19082) ) { 
include("home/something/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/folder/page3.html");
} 
else {
include("home/something/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/folder/page4.html"); }?>
```

What i wan't is to use Wordpress PHP function get_template_directory() inside of this just the way like i would do this

```
<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/folder/page1.html
```

Have been trying some diffrent solutins but PHP is not my strongest area so a little help would be fantastic.

Comment: `include(get_template_directory() . '/folder/page1.html')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include(get_template_directory() . "/folder/page1.html");
```

OR

It is better to store it in a variable not to cause overhead of calling the function a lot of times.

```
$temp_dir = get_template_directory() ;
include($temp_dir . "/folder/page1.html");
include($temp_dir . "/folder/page2.html");
include($temp_dir . "/folder/page3.html");
include($temp_dir . "/folder/page4.html");
```

Hope it helps.